# Pandas Matrix to Distance Matrix as fast as possible

Tags: python, performance, loops, pandas

I want to calculate a NxN similarity Matrix using the cosine distance formula of sklearn. My problem is that my Matrix is very very large. It has about 1000 entries. My current approach is very very slow and I need a real speed-up. Can anybody help me speeding the code up?

```
for i in similarity_matrix.columns:
    for j in similarity_matrix.columns:
        if i == j:
            similarity_matrix.ix[i,j] = 0
        else:
            similarity_matrix.ix[i,j] = cosine(documents[int(i)], documents[int(j)])
```

Bonus task: In addition I would like to use the weighted cosine formula. But it seems not to be implemented in sklearn? Is that true?

Comment: Did you try Scipy [cdist](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html)?

Comment: No thanks i will check the manual

Comment: You also try using `pivot_table`  in Pandas: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html

Comment: Pivot tables would probably work well too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using for-loops is not the ideal solution. I would recommend to fall back to the pdist functions of scipy. My read is that you don't mean your matrix has 1000 entries but 1000x1000? However Scipy can handle this easily.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist

res = pdist(documents.T, 'cosine')
distances = 1-pd.DataFrame(squareform(res), index=documents.columns, columns=documents.columns)
```

I have problems understanding how your weight vector looks like? Is is a constant value? Pdist allows for adding custom functions. For example you can calculate your cosine distance using numpy (which is also really fast)

```
pdist(X, lambda u, v: np.dot(np.dot(u, v), weightvec) / (norm(np.multiply(u, weightvec)) * norm(np.multiply(v, weightvec))))
```

Comment: Oh wait. Why is it 1-pd.Dataframe ?

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to calculate. There's an difference between cosine distance and cosine similarity. Check  wikipedia for more info https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity